# Google Play store rejects a react native app due to ‘non certified ad SDK’, how to resolve this?

Tags: react-native

Our simple app, which streams YouTube video content, has been rejected by the Google Play Store due to usage of a 'non certified ads SDK'. However, we have not used any ads sdk in the app.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Here is the list of dependencies.

```
{
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-listview": "^0.0.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-cached-image": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-pdf": "^5.1.3",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-searchbar": "^1.16.0",
    "react-native-sentry": "^0.43.2",
    "react-native-silent-switch": "thejump/react-native-silent-switch",
    "react-native-simple-store": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.8.6",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.11.0",
    "react-native-whc-loading": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-youtube": "GroupXTech/react-native-youtube",
    "react-navigation": "^3.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "reduxsauce": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

Comment: check this link :
https://forums.expo.io/t/play-store-issue-about-family-ads-program/41470/32

Comment: @WaleedNasir thank you.  I had already gone through it. It say about managed app and then eject to solve this issue. In our case, we have not used expo and it is like in ejected state only comparing to expo. Despite that our app is getting the same problem. Hence I posted here.